# (codesandbox) How can I get all the label `checkbox` and `first option` to be checked and selected by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In ReactJS, I am mapping some data and trying get all the label checkbox and its first value to be checked by default and also be able to uncheck checkbox that will uncheck selected radio button value as well.

## Codesandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-grass-0fc5x

I can get the checkbox to checked by default but not able get their value to be checked

```
toggleChange = (e, index) => {
   console.log(e.target, index);
   this.setState({
     isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
   });
};
```

```
handleChange = (selectedId) => {
  const { selectedItems } = this.state

  this.setState(state => ({
     selectedItems: [...state.selectedItems, {
       selectedId
     }]
  }))
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are missing `checked` prop in `checkbox` and `radio`.

Comment: Here is an example of handling multiple inputs, and it has the `checkbox` showcase: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs

Comment: @IvanBurnaev I also want to be able uncheck `checkbox` that will uncheck `option` aswell and update state

Comment: By `option` do you mean `radio input`?

Answer (score 1):

I've made some changes to your codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-williamson-pjkw9.

When you are working with checkboxes or radio buttons you should pay attention to the `checked` property instead of `value`. You may use `value` to pass some data to event handlers for sure, but the state of `checkiness`(one of my weird words) is defined by `checked` prop. If it is `true` - item becomes checked and vice versa.

And one more thing, the `checked` prop is cast to the boolean value, so if pass to it an empty string it gonna be unchecked, if the string is not empty - element will be checked.

Comment: Tx for the solution. It also needs to selected by default. Serhan's solution nearly achive what I am trying to do

Comment: Well, you can specify what checkboxes should be selected in `componentDidMount` method

Comment: @KaurB I've just updated the solution. Now all checkboxes are checked by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's work as you like. You can see this: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-agnesi-fevon-fork-fevon

Base logic is that your components' value should change depend of state data so firstly I mapped your data to React stage then I changed It when trigger any event.

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.selectedItems = []

    const data = result.map(item => {
      item.checked = true
      item.options.map((subItem, key) => {
        subItem.checked = key === 0 ? true : false
        return subItem
      })
      return item
    })

    this.state = {
      data: data
    }

    this.updateSelectedItems(this.state.data)
  }
```

Comment: Tnx mate, solution nearly works as expected. currently `handleChange` and `toggleChange` are directly setting the state I believe. is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: I figure out a mistake in code and I fixed It. Also I added selectedItems array variable, you can see it in console log after trigger any select event. As far as I know there is a no way to avoid `handleChange` and `toggleChange` against state. You’re welcome.